# Building insert statement with quotes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand how the single quotes work in SQL.
All I want to achieve is

```
INSERT INTO LOGTABLE 
            (ID, 
             ROLLNO) 
VALUES     ('E8645F55-A18C-43EA-9D68-1F9068F8A9FB', 
            28)
```

Here `ID` is a uniqueidentifier field and `rollNo` is an int.

So I have this sample test code:

```
 set @query = '

insert into fileLog
(
    id,
    rollNo
)
values
('+
'''' + NEWID() + '''' + ',' + 28 + 
')'

print @query
```

I have tried several combination of single quotes left and right but nothing works. I would really appreciate if someone could solve this. But in particular I wanted to know how many single quotes are required on both sides of a string to get something like 'SQL'.

Thanks

Comment: You only need 2 `'`s inside a string to indicate a `'` character. You can, for example, simplify `'''' + ','` to `''','`.

Comment: If you don't fully understand the risks of SQL Injection, then STOP RIGHT THERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm going to assume you need dynamic SQL for reasons not obvious in the question, since this doesn't seem to require dynamic SQL at all.)*

As @Gidil suggested, the problem here is trying to treat a uniqueidentifier as a string. In this case, there really isn't any reason to declare `NEWID()` in the outer scope, since you can simply say:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT ... VALUES(NEWID(), 28);';

PRINT @query;
```

*Now, [you should be using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as your parameter, because ultimately you should be executing this using `sp_executesql`, not `EXEC()`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).*

If you need to have a literal you can double up the quotes:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(32);
SET @string = 'foo';

SET @query = N'INSERT ... VALUES(''' + @string + ''', 28);';
```

However I find it more readable to use `CHAR(39)`:

```
SET @query = N'INSERT ... VALUES(' + CHAR(39) + @string + CHAR(39) + ', 28);';
```

And even better is to not append these variables to a string anyway. You should be using properly typed parameters where possible.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(32), @newid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @id INT;
SELECT @string = 'foo', @newid = NEWID(), @id = 28;

SET @query = N'INSERT ... VALUES(@string, @newid, @id);';

EXEC sp_executesql @query,
  N'@string VARCHAR(32), @newid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @id INT',
  @string, @newid, @id;
```

It's bulkier, sure, but it's much safer from SQL injection and it lets you stop trying to figure out and deal with the hassle of embedding single quotes into the string...

Comment: Thank you for taking effort in explaining this stuff. Top rated answer.

Answer (score 3):

My question is: Why are you using dynamic SQL?  It's one of those techniques that is useful in some situations, but can be abused easily.

As for the answer to your question, I use a technique to help minimize the flipping in and out of SQL construction:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @query = '

insert into fileLog
(
    id,
    rollNo
)
values
(''|NEWID|'', |INT|)'

SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '|NEWID|', NEWID())
SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '|INT|', 28)


PRINT @query
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching this technique. I am using dynamic SQL since the main insert is more complicated as I am inserting a pdf file using openrowset as well as several other columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @query = ' insert into fileLog (     id,     rollNo ) values (' + '''' + Cast(Newid() AS VARCHAR(100)) + '''' 
             + ',28)' 

PRINT @query
```

The problem isn't the quotes, but the data types.
NEWID isn't a string and neither is the number 28.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need dynamic SQL for some reason, you can probably just do this:

```
insert into fileLog
(
  id,
  rollNo
)
values
(
  NEWID(),
  28
)
```